# OpenSSL crypto error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line')]

Tags: python, openssl, certificate

I am getting the following error when trying to read a certificate:

```
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line')]
```

when running `OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, filename)`. I have made some research but was not able to find an answer specific to my case.

I tried checking if the file existed with `os.path.isfile(filename)` which returns `True`, but loading the certificate ONLY raises the error above.

Also, when executing on the terminal `openssl X509 -in file.pem`, it works like a charm.

The file.pem looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<<sensitive data>>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It seems to be valid since I able to perform basic `openssl` operations on the terminal. I am running CentOS 7, if that helps.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your PEM file contain the ` -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` or ` -----BEGIN X509 CERTIFICATE-----` lines before the base64 part?

Comment: Perhaps you can share your PEM content - If the PEM is sensitive, delete all but the first line of base64

Comment: Yes, the PEM does contain all begin/end certificate lines, I'll add it to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate,`load_certificate()` takes a buffer (string will do) containing the certificate, not a filename.

Your need to do:

```
with open(filename, "r") as my_cert_file:
    my_cert_text = my_cert_file.read()
    cert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, my_cert_text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But I have just a quick question, what is the "r" for?

Comment: @TheDrummerfromKubuntu the `r` is a mode of operation means to open a file for reading.